# Query data for unique combinations of facets without COUNT or SUM?

Tags: newrelic, nrql

I am currently trying to formulate a better query than what I currently have at the moment. For analysis reasons, I want to see the different combinations of facets a certain record has. Currently I use `SELECT COUNT(myRecord)FROM Metric FACET foo, bar`. This does the job, but I am wondering if it is possible to aggregate the data more efficiently. I use COUNT to group the values together, but I ultimately do not care about the COUNTed sum. Is there a better way to write this query that does not perform that additional calculation?

Answer (score 1):

I think that [uniques](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/query-your-data/nrql-new-relic-query-language/get-started/nrql-syntax-clauses-functions/#func-uniques) might be what you're looking for?

> Use the uniques() function to return a list of unique values recorded for an attribute over the time range specified.

For example, based on your current query you could get unique combinations of `foo` and `bar` without the count(s) by using this query:

```
SELECT uniques(tuple(foo, bar)) FROM Metric
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.